# Protractor issue: "angular could not be found on the window" because of wrong bash command

Tags: bash, protractor

I am running into the following issue:

```
Failures:
1) Signin page should allow user to signin
  Message:
    Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:8080/#/signin : retries looking for angular exceeded
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:8080/#/signin : retries looking for angular exceeded
        at /var/go/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16
        at /var/go/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/var/go/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
        at notify (/var/go/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
  Message:
    Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "angular could not be found on the window"
        at /var/go/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16
        at /var/go/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/var/go/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
        at notify (/var/go/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 10.742 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
Command ./snapci/end2end_tests.sh failed with status 1. Took 2 minutes 54.9 seconds.
```

I use protractor 1.8.0.

Here is my Protractor configuration:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['test/e2e/*.spec.e2e.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine2'
};

if (process.env.SNAP_CI) {
    exports.config.chromeDriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver';
    exports.config.chromeOnly= true;
}
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: From the spec:

```
describe('Signin page', function () {
    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/#/signin');
        browser.refresh();
    });
    it('should allow user to signin', function () {
        element(by.model('credentials.username')).sendKeys('balteo@example.fr');
        element(by.model('credentials.password')).sendKeys('------');
        element(by.id('submit')).click();
        expect(element(by.tagName('h2')).getText()).toBe('Dashboard');
    });
});
```

From index.html (which includes signin view):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="bignibou" ng-strict-di>
<head>
```

**edit 2**: Here is how I run protractor. I occurred to me that the java app might not have started by the time protractor starts... Is there a way to ensure the app gets a chance to start by using the bash shell?

```
#Install and start application
./gradlew assemble
java -jar bignibou-server/build/libs/bignibou-server.jar&

#Run end2end tests
node_modules/.bin/protractor bignibou-client/protractor.conf.js
```

Comment: Can you show what is inside the spec? Also, where is `ng-app` on the sign in page defined? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: I have edited my post

Comment: I have edited my post to take into account the fact that the app might not have had the time to start by the time protractor starts the tests. This is because I run the app in the background with `&`...

Comment: What angular version is used? Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick check: what if you add `rootElement: "html",` to your protractor configuration? Any difference?

Comment: @alecxe I have tried adding `rootElement: "html"`  as advised to no avail... I have the same error message.